# Elementary triangle /areas ratio question

Tags: geometry

In triangle $ABC$, let $D$ lie on $AC$, let $E$ lie on $AB$, let $F$ lie on $BD$, let $G$ lie on $CE$, with $BF/BD=x$ and $CG/CE=1-x$, where $0<x<1$. Find the ratio of the area of triangle $AFG$ to the area of quadrilateral $BCDE$. (I was told that the case $x=1/2$ was found by a Montreal high school student. It is not obvious to me that $F\not=G$.)

Comment: I get a strange diagram for this. Are you sure you typed it correctly? For example, you have both $D$ and $F$ on $\overline{AC}$, in the order $ADFC$, but you stick the definition of $E$ between the definitions of $D$ and $F$.

Comment: that should have been F on BD. i will fix it now

Comment: re-written with typo fixed

Comment: That ratio depends on the positions of D and E, so giving a meaningful answer is impossible without some other information.

Comment: I am sorry Arefino.You are mistaken.There is enough information for the RATIO.

Comment: @Aretino . Apologies to you. The Q was mis-stated.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT after the question was changed: see below for the original answer.

We can restrict ourselves WLOG, for simplicity, to the case of an isosceles triangle ($AB=AC$, see figure below). Let $AI$ be the altitude to base $BC$ and set: $a=BI=CI$, $h=AI$, $BE/BA=\beta$, $CD/CA=\gamma$.

We have then:
$$
EL=\beta h,\ BL=\beta a,\ DM=\gamma h,\ CM=\gamma a,
$$
and it is not difficult to compute the area of quadrilateral $BCDE$, as the sum of triangles $BLE$, $CMD$ and trapezoid $LMDE$. The result is:
$$
{\cal A}_{BCDE}=ah(\beta+\gamma-\beta\gamma).
$$
Let's turn now to triangle $AFG$ and observe that 
${\cal A}_{AFG}={1\over2}AK\cdot HJ$, where $H$ and $J$ are the projections of $F$ and $G$ on base $BC$, while $K$ is the intersection of $AI$ with line $FG$. 
As in the revised question, we set $x=BF/BD$ and choose $G$ on $CE$ such that $CG/CE=(1-x)$.
We have then:
$$
FH=x DM=\gamma hx,\quad GJ=(1-x)EL=\beta h(1-x),
$$
$$
BH=x BM=(2-\gamma) ax,\quad CJ=(1-x)CL=(2-\beta) a(1-x),
$$
from which we can compute:
$$
HJ=BC-BH-CJ=a\big(2-(2-\gamma) x-(2-\beta) (1-x)\big)=
a\big(\gamma x+\beta (1-x)\big)
$$
and
$$
IK=GJ+{IJ\over HJ}(FH-GJ)=
\beta h(1-x)+h\big(\gamma x-\beta (1-x)\big)
{1-(2-\beta)(1-x)\over\gamma x-\beta (1-x)}.
$$
It is then easy to find the area of triangle $AFG$:
$$
{\cal A}_{AFG}={1\over2}(AI-IK)\cdot HJ=ah x(1-x)(\beta+\gamma-\beta\gamma)
$$
so that the ratio of the areas is
$$
{{\cal A}_{AFG}\over{\cal A}_{BCDE}}=x(1-x).
$$

[image]

---

ANSWER TO THE ORIGINAL QUESTION.

As nobody answered, here's an example to support my comment above.

Let's take $x=1/2$, so that $BF/FD=CG/GE=1/2$ and consider at first the case where $E$ and $D$ are the midpoints of $AB$ and $AC$. The area of triangle $AED$ is $1/4$ the area of $ABC$, hence: ${\cal A}_{BCDE}={3\over4}{\cal A}_{ABC}$. On the other hand, $FG={1\over2}BC$ and the altitude of triangle $AFG$ with respect to base $FG$ is $5/6$ the altitude of triangle $ABC$ with respect to $BC$ (because segments $FD$ and $GE$ intersect at their common midpoint). Hence: ${\cal A}_{AFG}={5\over12}{\cal A}_{ABC}$ and the ratio of the areas is ${\cal A}_{AFG}/{\cal A}_{BCDE}=5/9$.

[image]

Consider now the case where $A\equiv E\equiv D$, always with $x=1/2$. In this case quadrilateral $BCDE$ degenerates into triangle $ABC$, while ${\cal A}_{AFG}={4\over9}{\cal A}_{ABC}$. Hence: ${\cal A}_{AFG}/{\cal A}_{BCDE}=4/9$.

[image]

We could also consider another limiting case, when $E$ and $D$ tend to $B$ and $C$ respectively. In this case ${\cal A}_{AFG}\to{1\over3}{\cal A}_{ABC}$ while
${\cal A}_{BCDE}\to0$, so that ${\cal A}_{AFG}/{\cal A}_{BCDE}\to\infty$.

These examples explain my comment above: the ratio of those areas depends not only on $x$, but also on the positions of $E$ and $D$.

Comment: I said $BF/FD=x$ and $CG/GE=1-x$..... You have $CG/GE=BF/FD=x.$

Comment: In all my examples $x=1/2$, hence $1-x=1/2$.

Comment: I owe you an apology as the Q is mis-stated. It should say $BF/BD=x$ and $CG/CE=1-x. $ Any comments before I fix it?

Comment: Go fix it, but please explain which is the source of this problem.

Comment: The case x=1 was told to me by a friend, and I generalized it.

Comment: I edited my answer to take into account the new question.

Comment: +1.... Taking $A$ as the origin (for convenience), we can also use  the scalar outer product $u\times v$: The area of $\triangle Auv$ is $|u\times v|/2.$ Since $\times$ distributes over vector addition, and $v\times u=-u\times v,$ we can arrive at the  desired ratio $x(1-x)$ fairly readily. The case $x=1/2$ was told to me by Michael Korenberg (Ph.D., Math.) in Toronto,ON.... With any $x\in (0,1)$ it has never been intuitively obvious to me that $F\ne G$.